# Stop SFMC email links from deeplinking to our Android app

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, android, deep-linking

We send out newsletters every week to our customers using SFMC. When someone clicks on the link we want to take customer to the browser instead of app in Android. We used *mc-deep-link="false"* to achieve this in iOS. But it's not working for Android. iOS fix is mentioned in documentation https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_exclude_ios_universal_link.htm&type=5

I have been told that our app is listening to the link domain 'click.mail.companyname.com.au' and tries to open it instead of it going to browser.
EDIT: Also we have different app per vertical, so say for vertical A when someone clicks on the newsletter link they go in the app for vertical A and we want that. But for vertical B,C&D since the domain in all our newsletters is the same 'click.mail.companyname.com.au' links from vertical B, C& D newsletters also ping app from vertical A and we get error.

So fix i'm looking for is that when I send newsletters for vertical B, C & D
when customer click on link it goes to their respective websites in browser instead of app for vertical A. Even though domain 'click.mail.companyname.com.au' is same across all of them

Comment: What you have been told is correct. Deeplinking is 100% an "app thing". Your Andoid application's manifest contains an `Intent-Filter` that explicitly declares that your application should listen for, and handle URLs constructed as you've noted. This is resolvable by your development team -- and they should know this as they had to add this `Intent-Filter` during development to make this functionality work in the first place.

Comment: Thank you Bill, actually other problem is we have separate apps for each vertical and but 'click.mail.companyname.com.au' domain is same for all the newsletters we send. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It's an application issue. The app is configured to hijack the URL you're sending. It wouldn't matter if you sent yourself a text message with that URL, clicked the URL from an email, or tried to open that URL manually. Your application is going to take control of the presentation of that URL. Google offers strategies for handling deeplinking, but any change is going to require an application update at this point.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking